# Gnuplot: adding functions to a fit

Tags: gnuplot, data-fitting

I would like to know how I can add 2 seperate functions of 2 different plots to form the fit for the 3rd one?

I am using Gnuplot 4.6.3.

So, I have the following functions: f(x)=a+b*x, g(x)=c+d*x.

Now the third plot is the total of the first and the second plot added together. So, how can I add the fits together and plot it to form the fitting of the third one?

What I have tried so far:

```
gnuplot> f(x)=a+b*x
gnuplot> g(x)=c+d*x
gnuplot> fit [:] [:] f(x) 'filename1.dat' u 1:(log(-$2)) via a,b 
gnuplot> fir [:] [:] g(x) 'filename2.dat' u 1:(log(-$2)) via c,d
I get results for the variables a,b,c,d. 
gnuplot> plot 'filename1.dat', f(x) via a,b
gnuplot> replot 'filename2.dat', g(x) via c,d
gnuplot> replot 'filename1+2.dat', f(x)+g(x)
```

The 3rd fit is completely off, so I know I did something wrong, but what?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The commands you list do exactly what you expect.

One likely error in your post (and possibly in the commands you issued in gnuplot) is that fits is done for `1:(log(-$2))` and not the plot of the data.
But then, you also have `fir` for `fit`, and `via` in `plot` must raise errors.

Without more information on your data, it is difficult to spot another problem.

Comment: Thanks! Ah! Yes, I just mistyped fir, oops. 
I will use the errors to get a better fit then!